# Where do I find the Lord of the Rings miniatures for D&D

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, miniatures

Years ago we used to have wonderful 25mm miniatures that we used for our D&D games.  I seem to remember they were based on the Lord of the Rings.  They were grey rather than silver and were  amazing detail.

Can anyone remember the name of these and where I can get them now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know that [Citadel/Games Workshop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Games_Workshop#Licensing) produced 28mm pewter Lord of the Rings miniatures years ago for MERP (a complete list is available on [solelegends.com](http://www.solegends.com/citlotr/indexblist.htm).  Those are out of production, unfortunately; they still produce [Lord of the Rings miniatures](http://www.games-workshop.com/gws/catalog/landing.jsp?catId=cat210006&rootCatGameStyle=lotr&_requestid=801807) for their own tabletop battle game, but 25mm and in plastic, like most of their miniatures now, and they also have their [strategy battle universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Games_Workshop#The_Lord_Of_The_Rings_Strategy_Battle_Game_universe), which has 10mm miniatures fit for more epic battles.

[Mithril miniatures](http://www.mithril.ie/) also produces miniatures for MERP, though unfortunately, in 32mm scale and 54mm scale.

Mithril Miniatures was predated in their license by Grenadier in 1985, a now defunct miniatures company that produced a licensed Lord of the Rings miniature line.  They transferred their license to Mithril in 1987. [(1)](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Middle-earth_Role_Playing)

I think those are/were the only choices for official Lord of the Rings/MERP miniature lines.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, it was the [Mithril](http://mithril.ie/) range I was thinking of. I'm not sure how readily available they are anymore. They had an amazing range with all the Lord of the Rings characters that you could use for your own.

Answer (score 2):

There is the Citadel line - depending upon how long ago, these might be them, for use with their LOTR tabletop battle game. Which said game isn't that old - 2001 or so, and it's been 28-30mm since launch.

Also unlikely are Mithril's lines, which are pretty recent; 32 might be used with D&D maps at scale, but 54's certainly wouldn't, and both are unlikely to be confused with 25mm figs if any 25/28's were in use.

However, since you stated 25mm, and said "Years ago"... and that standard's been out of D&D use for about 12 years, I find it more likely that it's the old Rolemaster-derived Middle Earth Role Play, and it's associated line.

For an example of them:
[http://www.miniatures-workshop.com/lostminiswiki/index.php?title=MERP_Middle_Earth_Characters_(M443_-_M452)](http://www.miniatures-workshop.com/lostminiswiki/index.php?title=MERP_Middle_Earth_Characters_%28M443_-_M452%29)

Further, there was an even older line of minis before then, but I forget who released them.

Comment: That older line *was* Citadel/Games Workshop.  When ICE had the license for MERP (Middle Earth Roleplaying), Citadel was contracted to distributed MERP overseas, and to create a miniatures line.  Examples of the complete line are shown at solelegends.com (direct link in my question).  This was back in the 80's.

Comment: It was the older Mithril Minatures I was thinking of.